# How to play an in downloading progress video file in IOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming

I'm assigned to implement a iphone app that can download video files from a server, and to play that video while the video file is written to the disk; something likes

(Movie player)<--read--[###### iphone flaskdisk ######]<--write---(Downloader)

I know that I would use HTTP video streaming play a remote video stream, but what i need is the video file is saved in flask mem after playing.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to play a video from a URL, you can easily play the video while simultaneously download the video on another thread (if you are short on time)...

Alternatively, you can create your own video player that handles this function. Application sin the App Store do already do this (check out any video downloader application)

Thanks!

Comment: thanks, can you point me to some good examples? Your suggestion would work, but our video files are relatively big, so it will cost user twice for download and playing in two different threads unless the data is somehow cached.

Comment: Take a look at: libavcodec and libavformat from the ffmpeg library.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to compile those libs for iOS, Do you know any ffmpeg example or sample code for iOS?

Comment: take a look at kxmovie on github